# How do I start a new activity when a listItem is selected?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My main activity page for the android app is mainly a listView and on clicking an item in that list I would like a new activity to start. I have created the intent and such as follows in the onCreate method of my MainActivity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);   

    final MainActivity context  = this;

    lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, SubActivity.class);
            myIntent.addFlags(position); //Optional parameters
            context.startActivity(myIntent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

My new activity class looks like this:

```
public class SubActivity extends MainActivity{

ArrayList<String> sublist = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> subadapter;

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> corrReceipts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int position = intent.getFlags(); //this gives me the index of the receipt

    corrReceipts = super.addedReceipts;

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello");


    subadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sublist);
    ListView slv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sublistview);
    slv.setAdapter(subadapter); 


    sublist.addAll(corrReceipts.get(position));
    subadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    setContentView(slv);

}
```

}

I have my subActivity class extending MainActivity because it needs to access an array from which to get the information from. When I run this code, and click a list item, nothing happens. Any help as to what I'm doing wrong would be of great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you want is an `ItemClickListener` not an `ItemSelectedListener`.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, SubActivity.class);
        myIntent.addFlags(position); //Optional parameters
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

`OnItemSelectedListener` is used for Spinners, and `OnItemClickListener` is used for ListViews.

Comment: I didn't know that the selectedListener was for spinners so thank you for that. I made the change but nothing is happenning

Comment: startActivity(myIntent); doesn't need context in the start